# How to receive Push notifications from server (AWS or app engine) to a local script running on windows computer?

Tags: android, windows, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I have an app that communicates some data to a server (AWS or app engine). Now that data is supposed to be sent to certain computer all running windows 7. I want a script on those computers to recieve the push notification and make a pop up appear so that the user know some new data has been recieved.

Can anyone tell me if its possible. I am only finding push notification for android devices. What about a windows computer ?

Also, if its not possible, what would be the best way to do this. I knwo i can poll the server continuously but that will just cause too much unnecessary http request being generated. I can also try to implement a local server to which the app engine can send data, but just want to knwo if there is an easier more simpler way to dot his.

Thanks

Comment: try using something like ZeroMQ (zeromq.org) to implement a PUB/SUB pattern. It's reliable and easy to use across platforms and programming languages (although the initial learning curve is steep).

Comment: If timing is fairly relaxed, send an email to the Windows computer.

Comment: If your site is very busy then a client polling may be unwanted overhead. However there are benefits to polling if this is not the case. A quick status check function should be very fast, and will have the benefit of keeping an instance active. Again all depends on your load, but it is not always the case that polling would be bad.